# sass not working. scss file changes are not applying to css

Tags: sass

I have set up Sass and created a project it was worked nicely but after restarting my computer, Now if I change, add or remove anything from my `style.scss` file it does not affect the `style.css` Before restarting it was functional and worked nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using command line to watch your SaSS file and compile your CSS? If so you may want to run your “—watch” command again.

Comment: Yes, I am using command line. how to run watch? and how I can compile using GUI.?

Comment: You can read about using command line watch to compile in the SaSS guide (http://sass-lang.com/guide). I’ve never used any programs with a GUI for compiling SaSS, not sure there is one.